# Flat File Connection Manager, other tool windows font size is too small

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

A few of the tool windows in VS are showing font sizes that are really odd, wuch as the Flat File Connection Manager and the package progress window.

Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Envrionment -> Fonts and Colors

Comment: You might have the text size zoomed.  Hit the Start button, then type *change display settings* in the search box on the taskbar. From the list of results, choose Change display settings and then make sure it's set for 100%.  If that doesn't work, reinstall VS.  If that doesn't work, reinstall Windows.

Comment: Your Windows display settings might be off somehow - check the settings for 'Scale and layout' under Windows display settings (right click on desktop and choose 'Display settings').  If anything other than 100% that might explain why things look odd.

Comment: But i have 250% as recommended and if i go anything lesser im unable to see the text.